# more syntax in Java

Tags: java, keyword

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C5VE.png)

Hey everyone, i'm just beginning to learn programming. Can anyone explain to me what the 'more' keyword does, actually? I searched on the internet but couldn't find a simple explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`more`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html) is a unix command to display the contents of a file, paginated. It has nothing to do with Java.